# Does violating the proportional hazards assumption always matter?

Tags: survival, cox-model

I've seen a couple of posts saying that violating the proportional hazards assumption (PHA) doesn't always matter, but several more suggesting it does and that the model needs to be modified accordingly.

I'd like to know whether I need to worry about it in my case. I'm testing whether the latency of a species to eat depends on which *treatment* group they are in (a binary category). I'm using coxme in R, as there are repeated measurements for each individual. I have included three other variables - two categorical and one continuous. Running cox.ph() to check the PHA shows that my variable of interest (the *treatment* group) violates it (p = 0.04). Another variable also does to a greater extent (tiny p-value), so I've stratified by that. Running cox.ph() again shows *treatment* is now at p = 0.02.

I'm wondering whether this matters. I'm a novice to survival analyses, but my inclination is "no". There is no overall difference between the *treatment* groups (as expected), the plots of the survival curves show they are so close over the whole time frame that their overlapping isn't weird, and I was only testing to see if there was a difference, not to estimate the hazard. I would have used a linear regression had there not been censored data (the subjects were given 600 seconds to eat, and most ate within a few seconds).

Does it sound like it is OK to proceed as is?

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about the nature of the censoring. For example, did you just stop recording time-to-eat at some fixed point in time, so that all censored values are simply something like 'greater than 2 minutes'? If so, there might be an alternative to a Cox model. Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks - that information is now included.

Answer (score 3):

It seems strange that you would find a "significant" violation of proportional hazards (PH) if there weren't some association of `treatment` with time-to-eat. The key here might be in your statement:

> the subjects were given 600 seconds to eat, and most ate within a few seconds.

This suggests that you might have separate states of rapid-eating versus slow-or-never-eating, and that your `treatment` might have different effects on the two states. The danger in just accepting your initial finding of no `treatment` difference is that you might miss an interesting true difference between early and late times. If the PH assumption doesn't hold, then your coefficient estimates are event-averaged values that might not represent the data well.

A smoothed plot of scaled Schoenfeld residuals (provided by the R `cox.zph()` function that tests for PH) could be very informative, as it shows directly how the estimated hazard changes over time. Something as simple as a step-function in time for the `treatment` coefficient might then show something useful. Section 4.1 of the R [time dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) demonstrates how to implement that.

Other thoughts:

Your data might not meet PH but instead follow an accelerated failure time (AFT) model, like a lognormal or log-logistic model.

Depending on the distribution of event times, you might consider a type of hurdle model that models both the probability of being in the rapid-eating group and the time-to-event within that group.

There are other ways to deal with simple censoring like this, in particular [tobit models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobit_model). [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/544652/28500) shows how to include a random effect. But that wouldn't deal with the possible early/late difference directly; you would see that difference only in the patterns of residuals. A proportional-odds model also might be considered with this type of censoring, but again a true early/late difference wouldn't be found except perhaps as a violation of the proportional-odds assumption.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I arbitrarily divided early and late responders and there is indeed a difference early on. I tried a tobit model but it wouldn't run because it was singular, but, as you say, it wouldn't model the early/late difference anyway. I'll keep looking into the other models. Is a hurdle model not just for count data?

Comment: @Picapica "cure models" in survival analysis are a conceptual equivalent to hurdle models: a cure model combines the probability of _never_ having the event along with the time-to-event analysis for those who have it. In your case, I suspect that a simple step-function in time for the treatment coefficient, as described in Section 4.1 of the R [time dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf), will do what you need.

Comment: This looked really promising! I followed their example, but unfortunately I get a warning message when using my own data: "Error in coxme.fit(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights, : No starting estimate was successful". I'll probably have to make a new question, though I'm not confident I'll be able to sort it.

Comment: @Picapica playing with the starting estimates in `coxme` would probably fix this, but it might be simpler to use the standard `coxph()` function with a `cluster()` term for the individuals. That provides robust estimates of the coefficient standard errors to account for the repeated measures. It sounds like you have a reasonably complete data set so that missing data (which mixed models like `coxme` can handle better) isn't a problem. See discussion on [GEE vs mixed models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16390/28500).

Comment: I wasn't able to find any helpful starting estimates for the coxme model. Running coxph() works though doesn't show me the pattern I was expecting based on running the separate models (it says there is no difference between early and late - but maybe I am wrong to give weight to that) and the PHA is still violated (this time for TrialType:strata(tgroup) ). Another thing is that I get NAs for both TrialTypeTreatment:tgroup estimates and I'm not sure why - is it supposed to be two baselines? Also I was hoping to get a random effects estimate out. I really appreciate all the help by the way!

Comment: @Picapica your question on using `coxme` was too programming-specific to be on-topic here. It might help for you to show (maybe best in a new question) the plot of smoothed Schoenfeld residuals over time for your model that failed the `cox.zph()` test, probably best for the model stratified by the nuisance variable. The magnitude and form of that smoothed plot might contain specific clues for how best to proceed. Please do _not_ use the `ggsurvminer` package for that plot, as it has suffered from a serious coding error in Schoenfeld plots that might not yet be fixed.