# Censoring on a different measurement?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, censoring

This is a split-off from [a different question about right-censored data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/601122/modeling-semicontinuous-data-with-upper-bound). I think that one has been handled nicely. However, there is a corollary. In addition to analysis of time to complete a task with censorship at time = X (maximum time allowed), the researchers want the distance traveled over that time to also be analyzed against the same variables. How do I do this, when the censorship criterion is not the response variable?

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that failed/completed is a binary variable that I can use as a covariate in the model! Then I can predict and infer on the basis of that covariate.